# How to check if lines in string are separated by space?

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm building a program that gets the publisher of the book by scanning its title page and using OCR … since publishers are always at the bottom of the title page I'm thinking that a detecting lines that are separated by space is a solution but I don't know how to test for that. Here is my code:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
Dim reader As New StringReader(txtOCR.Text)
Dim iCounter As Integer = 0
While True
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
    If line Is Nothing Then Exit While

    'i want to put the condition here

End While
txtPublisher.Text = builder.ToString()
```

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph thanks for editing my question im sorry if i cant explain clearly.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean empty lines? Then you can do this:

```
Dim bEmpty As Boolean
```

And then inside the loop:

```
If line.Trim().Length = 0 Then
    bEmpty = True
Else
    If bEmpty Then
        '...
    End If

    bEmpty = False
End If
```

Comment: thanks but my problem is after detecting the second empty line how to store the next line which is probably the publisher to a textbox?

Comment: @user2107624 You loop on each line, you can use a boolean to know if last line was empty. I edit my answer.

Comment: i think i know now thanks @SysDragon im sorry if ask noob questions but thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do the following: from the bottom, go up until you find the first non-empty line (no idea how the OCR works … maybe the bottom-most line is always non-empty, in which case this is redundant). In the next step, go up until the first empty line. The text in the middle is the publisher.

You don’t need the `StringReader` for that:

```
Dim lines As String() = txtOCR.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)
Dim bottom As Integer = lines.Length - 1

' Find bottom-most non-empty line.
Do While String.IsNullOrWhitespace(lines(bottom))
    bottom -= 1
Loop

' Find empty line above that
Dim top As Integer = bottom - 1

Do Until String.IsNullOrWhitespace(lines(top))
    top -= 1
Loop

Dim publisherSubset As New String(bottom - top)()
Array.Copy(lines, top + 1, publisherSubset, 0, bottom - top)
Dim publisher As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, publisherSubset)
```

But to be honest I don’t think this is a particularly good approach. It’s inflexible and doesn’t cope well with unexpected formatting. I’d instead use a regular expression to describe what the publisher string (and its context) looks like. And maybe even that isn’t enough and you have to put some thought into describing the *whole* page to extrapolate which of the bits is the publisher.

Comment: yes this is just one of my conditions thanks for your suggestion.. i will try the code.. the bottom-most line is an empty line that how ocr works i think

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the publisher is always on the last line and always comes after an empty line. Then perhaps the following?

```
    Dim Lines as New List(Of String)
    Dim currentLine as String = ""
    Dim previousLine as String = ""

    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(txtOCR.Txt)
    currentLine = reader.ReadLine
     If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(previousLine) then lines.Add(currentLine)
     previousLine = currentLine
    End Using

    txtPublisher.Text = lines.LastOrDefault()
```

To ignore if the previous line is blank/empty:

```
Dim Lines as New List(Of String) 
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(txtOCR.Txt) 
lines.Add(reader.ReadLine) 
End Using 

txtPublisher.Text = lines.LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: The only way it will possibly return the first line is if no other lines in the txt file are preceded by a blank/empty line beforehand. I have edited my answer to include the following scenario: If you want the last line of the txt regardless of what line is preceding.